# Sqoop export to teradata gives error when the content has comma delimiter

Tags: csv, teradata, sqoop, delimiter

I have a table with 10 columns, in which one column is a description of datatype string and can have free form text of maximum length 255. My column is having many special characters like ()$&*,. when I try to export data into teradata, I am getting the below exception.

```
com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.26] [Error 1382] [SQLState HY000] The batch is empty.
```

I am converting a parquet file into a csv with different delimiters but none of them worked. I have seen an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 10` as well. This made me think if the delimiter is causing the issue and considering a row with more than 10 while inserting. Is there a better way to export data using sqoop for free form text having special characters. Any help would be appreciated.

I am able to export the same table into Oracle without any issue and, except that particular column, I am able to export the table with the rest of the columns.

Comment: I would look into wrapping each field into double-quotes, and escaping inner double-quotes, if you have any.

Comment: Hi @access_granted, my code for converting a parquet into csv already does that. After the conversion, I looked into the data set and see that my description column is surrounded by double-quotes if there is a comma delimiter in it. Do I need to do anything more in specific?

Comment: I would use double-quotes for each field, regardless of its contents, and escaping inner double-quotes, not commas. Don't believe any other symbols you referenced would need additional escaping.